# Cumulative Sum and Percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Can someone help me in getting the cumulative sum and percentage. I have three fields in the table "capability"

```
vertical|Defects(F)|Defects(NF)|

Billing | 193      |678
Provi   |200       |906
Billing |232       |111
Analyt  |67        |0
Provi   |121       |690
```

I would want the final output to be

```
Vertical|Total Defects|Cumulative Defects|Cumulative%

Billing |1214         | 1214             |37.96%
Provi   |1917         | 3131             |97.90%
Analyt  |67           | 3198             |100.00%
```

Please note that I have around 3mn rows and data keeps increasing day on day.

Comment: There's a lot of buttons at the top of the edit window. `{}` will indent by 4 spaces and mark something up as code.

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way to get the cumulative sum is by using a correlated subquery -- unless you have the full power of window functions as in SQL Server 2012

However this poses several challenges.  First, you need to summarize by the verticals.  Then you need to order the verticals in the right order.  Finally, you need to output the results the way you want them:

This should come close to what you want:

```
with d as
      (select vertical, sum(Defects_N + Defects_NF) as Defects,
              (case when vertical = 'Billing' then 1
                    when vertical = 'Provi' then 2
                    else 3
               end) as num
       from t
       group by vertical
      )
select vertical, defects as TotalDefects, cumDefects,
       100 * cast(cumDefects as float) / fulldefects as DefectPercent
from (select d.*,
             (select sum(defects) from d d2 where d2.num <= d.num
             ) as cumdefects,
             SUM(defects) over () as fulldefects
      from d
     ) d
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon for this, I got this working, but the fundamental challenge I am having is, I need to order the data ascending based on TotalDefects, rather than ordering by vertical. Any suggestions..

Comment: @youbarajsharma . . . Add an `order by` clause, such as `order by TotalDefects` or `order by TotalDefects desc`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok may be this will help someone trying to get the similar output. Here is what I did to get the desired output. Thanks a lot gordon, your suggestion actually helped me to make this possible

```
with d as
      (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER  
(ORDER BY SUM([DEFECTS(F)]+[DEFECTS(NF)]) asc) NUM,
VERTICAL,
SUM([DEFECTS(F)]+[DEFECTS(NF)]) AS [DEFECTS]
 FROM Capability
GROUP BY VERTICAL

      )
select left(vertical,5) as Vertical, defects as TotalDefects, cumDefects,
       cast(cumDefects as float) / fulldefects as DefectPercent
from (select d.*,
             (select sum(defects) from d d2 where d2.num <= d.num
             ) as cumdefects,
             SUM(defects) over () as fulldefects
      from d

     ) d
```